# nodejs fifo works when piping to stdout but not when piping to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, bash, streaming

I'm playing around with node and fifos and am getting some bizarre behavior I can't explain. Basically, I'm creating a fifo using spawn, creating a writestream to that fifo, piping data to the writestream, and spawning a cat command that reads from the fifo. It works if I then pipe the results of the cat command to stdout, but doesn't work if I pipe them to another file. See the code below

Note: this behavior only exhibits when you are writing enough data to hit the write buffer

```
var fs = require('fs'),
stream = require('stream');

// create read stream
var rs = fs.createReadStream('testinput')

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// create fifo
var fifo = spawn('mkfifo', ['testfifo']);

fifo.on('exit', function() { // when fifo is created, proceed

    // create outfile and attach fifostream
    var ws = fs.createWriteStream('testoutput')
    var fifows = fs.createWriteStream('testfifo');

    // pipe to fifo
    rs.pipe(fifows);

    // spawn process to read fifo
    var prog = spawn('cat', ['testfifo']);

    // send results somewhere
    prog.stdout.pipe(process.stdout); // this works
    // prog.stdout.pipe(ws); // this doesn't
})
```

I should probably say why I'm trying to do this. I want to have a stream, which is coming in from a websocket be used as the argument of a spawned command that is expecting a file. So in the example above a stream coming in can be fed to cat and behave as if cat was just reading a file.